# add value every 5 minutes and reset textview

Tags: android

I am a beginner in Android. I have created a chronometer and it works. I added a new function (every 5 minutes a value 1000 shown in the textview, after 10 minutes it takes 2000). This function works but if I click a button exit and I re-open the chronometer, after 5 minutes the value continues to add to the previous value but I want to reset this value once I click exit. I have used 
`finish(); handler.removeCallbacks(null); handler.postDelayed(test, 100);` but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks.

```
btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (lastPause != 0) {
                    chronometer.setBase(chronometer.getBase() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastPause);
                } else {
                    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                }

                chronometer.start();
                suppl();
                btnStart.setEnabled(false);
                btnStop.setEnabled(true);
                btnExit.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chronometer.stop();
                onPause();
                lastPause = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                btnStart.setEnabled(false);
                btnExit.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                handler.removeCallbacks(null);
                handler.postDelayed(test, 100);


            }
        });
    }


Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable test;
    public void suppl() {

        test = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                count += 1000;
                tprice.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                handler.postDelayed(test, 5000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(test, 5000);

    }


    public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       if (handler != null)
           handler.removeCallbacks(test);


    }
```

Comment: start Activity with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` or  add `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in `AndroidManifest`

Comment: All you are trying to do is reset chronometer time correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: i want to reset handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a [`TimerTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) for this purpose.

While using time task you can cancel all the pending tasks by using `cancel()` on the timer.

if you have any doubts in this solution, let me know.

Comment: can you give an example,I searched but nothing works

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/1050/java-timer-timertask-example.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-timertask-class-java/

Comment: I can not reset timer

Comment: I do " tprice.setText(String.valueOf(count-=count)); " inside btnExit and it works, thanks

Comment: great. I'll appreciate if you'd like to also upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use CountDownTimer

```
 CountDownTimer CD = new CountDownTimer(11000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    xo = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);

                    secondsleftimg.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

Replace this line of code :

```
 handler.removeCallbacks(null);
```

with this  :

```
   handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); // it will remove all hadler


    btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           focus.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
          handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
           lastPause= 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: my chronometer reset successfully but not the handler

Comment: @jose because you are passing null in handler you need to pass the your runnable inside removecallback().Let me know if still facing issue